# Another question of index notation in tensor calculus

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I have this equation 
$$\nabla_{a}(g_{bc}\lambda^{c})=(\nabla_{a}g_{bc})\lambda^{c}+g_{bc}\nabla_{a}\lambda^{c}$$

And making some calculations
$$     \lambda^{c} (\nabla_{a}g_{bc})=    \nabla_{a}(g_{bc}\lambda^{c})- g_{bc}\nabla_{a}\lambda^{c}     $$

$$     \lambda^{c} (\nabla_{a}g_{bc})=    \nabla_{a}(\lambda_{b})- g_{bc}\nabla_{a}\lambda^{c}     $$

And I want to get an expression for $\nabla_{a}g_{bc}$, so I make this

$$     \lambda^{c} (\nabla_{a}g_{bc})=   \frac{\lambda}{\lambda} (\nabla_{a}(\lambda_{b})- g_{bc}\nabla_{a}\lambda^{c} )    $$

With $\lambda=\lambda^{e}\lambda_{e}$. Then
$$     \lambda^{c} (\nabla_{a}g_{bc})=   \frac{\lambda^{e}\lambda_{e}}{\lambda} (\nabla_{a}(\lambda_{b})- g_{bc}\nabla_{a}\lambda^{c} )    $$
Changing indexes
$$     \lambda^{e} (\nabla_{a}g_{be})=   \frac{\lambda^{e}\lambda_{e}}{\lambda} (\nabla_{a}(\lambda_{b})- g_{bc}\nabla_{a}\lambda^{c} )    $$
Then
$$     (\nabla_{a}g_{be})=   \frac{\lambda_{e}}{\lambda} (\nabla_{a}(\lambda_{b})- g_{bc}\nabla_{a}\lambda^{c} ) +k_{a}   $$
With $k_{a}$ such that $\lambda^{a}k_{a}=0$

This is right? And if is not, there is a way that I can get an expression for $\nabla_{a}g_{be}$

**Edit**

Suppose that we are not working in $\nabla_{a}g_{bc}=0$

Comment: $\nabla_{a}g_{be}=0$ is an independent calculation. It ensures the connection is metric compatible, i.e., it ensures vector angles and magnitudes are invariant when $g$ is parallel transported. 

If $\nabla_{a}g_{be}\neq0$ then it implies your metric may degenerate.

The connection can be affine or Levi-Cevita - and you can use the Christoffel symbols either way - but there are potentially an infinite number of affine connections which may be compatible with the metric - and the Christoffel symbols may not posses the same symmetry properties as the Levi-Cevita connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, you are simply rearranging your original expression

$$\nabla_{a}(g_{bc}\lambda^{c})=(\nabla_{a}g_{bc})\lambda^{c}+g_{bc}\nabla_{a}\lambda^{c}$$

and attempting to isolate an expression for $\nabla_a g_{bc}$.  This is not possible, simply because every possible covariant derivative "candidate" satisfies the "product rule" exactly as this one does.  Without additional information, you cannot determine how $\nabla$ acts on the metric.

---

From an index manipulation point of view, in general one cannot "invert" contraction, in the same way that one cannot simply invert a dot product.  Explicitly, your calculation fails here:

$$\lambda^{c} (\nabla_{a}g_{bc})=   \frac{\lambda^{e}\lambda_{e}}{\lambda} (\nabla_{a}(\lambda_{b})- g_{bc}\nabla_{a}\lambda^{c} )$$

The index $e$ on the right hand side is contracted over, and therefore does not constitute a free index.  When you relabel the left hand side
$$\lambda^e(\nabla_a g_{be}) = \ldots$$

and then try to remove the $\lambda^e$ by contracting with $\lambda_e$, you are forgetting that $e$ is already a dummy index.  In short, to re-use more familiar notation, you have that
$$\vec \lambda \cdot \vec F =  \ldots$$
and are trying to get an expression for $\vec F$, which you simply cannot do in the absence of additional information.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get an expression for $\nabla_{a}g_{bc}$

If you are using the [Levi-Civita connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection), then the covariant derivative of the metric is *zero* by the *definition* of that connection.

See [this PSE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47919/why-is-the-covariant-derivative-of-the-metric-tensor-zero).

If you don’t know which connection you’re supposed to be using, you’re almost certainly supposed to be using Levi-Cevita’s. It’s the unique torsion-free connection that preserves lengths and angles under parallel transport.

Comment: Oh that is the problem, I'm not using levi civita conecction. I know that in $\nabla_{a}g_{bc}=0$ when torsion is $0$.

Comment: Your previous questions indicate that you have just started to study differential geometry, so I find it somewhat... surprising!... that you are using a connection with torsion. Please ignore my answer. It is the right answer for the other 99.99% of readers.